# copying oracle table with calculated indexes

Tags: oracle, copying, database-indexes

I would like to know if I can copy oracle table content from another table with exactly the same structure. I want to copy all of the data (or sometimes a part of it), including the calculated indexes. That is, I don't want to redo the calculations for the indexes, or to rebuild them.  Can this be done?  A related question: Where does oracle stores the informations when it calculates an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not copy the calculated index to another table because the index contains ROWID is the physical address of the table row (object identifier, file identifier, block ID, offset in the block).
You must create your own index for the new table.
The rows of the new index will contain the physical address of the new table.
(new object identifier, file identifier, block identifier, offset in the block)

To increase the speed of index creation, you can use parallel index creation.
Parallel index build/scans is only available Enterprise Edition.

```
CREATE INDEX    my_idex    ON     my_table(p1, p2, p_id) PARALLEL 35;
```

Comment: This seem to put an end to my hopes, but it is very informative answer !

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can copy the calculated index in another table. But you can copy the whole contents in another table like

Create table destination as
Select * from source;

And the indexes information can be seen in all_indexes .

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, The `create table dest  from source` doesn't  put the indexes in the resulting table. My aim is to use the destination table with the indexes .. I would like to avoid recreating them and recalculate them ..(because on huge table it could be very time consumming, anf they are already calculed in the source table ..)